# <Point object at XXX> is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, django, django-haystack

I have the following problem with Django 1.6, Python 3.3 and haystack. Basically I'm trying to use LocationField in haystack, but unfortunately not very successfully.

Here is the exception, which python trow.

```
<Point object at 0x7fe54e41d9a0> is not JSON serializable
```

And my code in search_indexes.py:

```
class ListingIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    ....
    location = indexes.LocationField(model_attr='get_location')
    ....

    def get_model(self):
        return Listing
```

And in the models.py():

```
...
from haystack.utils.geo import Point
...

class Listings(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_location(self):
        return Point(self.lng, self.lat)
```

I have searched for a several hours in Google and SO and learn a lot of for serialization Django objects, but doesn't find any result, which help me to found a solution here. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a full traceback. The exception you're getting is caused by trying to serialize object instances as JSON, which is apparently done somewhere outside of the code you've decided to post.

Comment: This is because Django by default use JSONSerializer that can't serialize python objects. You can change this in Django settings by changing JSONSerializer to PickleSerializer (which is not quite safe) read more about this in Django docs.

Comment: Once you know how to change the serializer, have a look at the module documentation for json. You can add a parameter `default` that transfers the object into json serializable form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my the solution here. The issue was that when I update the Elasticsearch, pass as parameter for the location Point object(as the field was from type Location, I thought that is the right way to do that), but actually, that what I should to do is to pass a json with. Below is the code:

```
location = self.get_location()
location_es = "{0},{1}".format(location.y, location.x)
```

And after that, when I updating Elasticsearch, using location_es, not location as parameter for the location field.
Thank you for your answers ! :)